# What problems could I meet with Laravel 4 on PHP 5.3.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I know that the Laravel 4 requirements are PHP >= 5.3.7 but my client must recent application server only has PHP 5.3.3. Yes, three years old version...

I need more arguments to explain the situation and find a solution with him (no move, upgrade or cloud hosting).

The questions are the following :

- Can I make L4 run with PHP 5.3.3 ?
- If not, why ?
- If so, how and with what limitations ?

[EDIT] What I know about my client configuration is : Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.3 on VMWare virtual machine with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: I can't, the project is not yet really sold !

Comment: VirtualBox, CentOS (or anything) and manual installation of 5.3.3?

Comment: My guess is that you will encounter too many problems to make this work. Look here http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php

Comment: @BenSwinburne I have edited my question : Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.3 on VMWare virtual machine with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: What I was saying was you could replicate the environment easily using the above free tools. The process would take about 30 minutes to complete and you can use the environment for testing. CentOS is about as close as you'll get to RHEL. VMWare vs VirtualBox in this context is negligible, and Apache and PHP you can install yourself to whatever version on your testing environment.

Comment: Alexandre Butynski, I have no clue why you think asking here is of use. If the Laravel projects says that the minimum PHP requirements are PHP 5.3.7, I bet they do it for a reason. That reason you will find with that project, and less here on Stackoverflow (I *assume*). Just saying as you have a *very specific* question.

Comment: Sure @hakre, it's just a try. If somebody already has the same problem I could save hours. I also consider this question good to learn about the core of Laravel and PHP. It's not only know if I can do something or not. It's understand why :)

Answer (score 12):

Laravel 4 requires PHP `5.3.7` due to using the bcrypt algorithm when hashing passwords, which received a huge bugfix at that version.

Have a look at this article for bringing the requirement of PHP for Laravel 4 down to `5.3.2`: http://laravel.io/topic/39/laravel-4-easily-extended

EDIT: here is an archived version of the linked article, as the original appears to be down:
https://web.archive.org/web/20130805153640/http://laravel.io/topic/39/laravel-4-easily-extended

NOTE: some PHP versions of `5.3.3` on certain distros do have the bcrypt algorithm fix backported into them, such as RedHat. You can read on how you can test if the distro you are using is one of them [here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat#requirements); if it is, your distro supports the fix, and in turn supports Laravel 4 out of the box.

Comment: Dead link? Or is their website down? Link returns "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Comment: Edited my answer to include a link to an archived version of the article.

Answer (score 2):

I had an experience with a remote webhost that offers several versions of php, and somehow, was set to an older default version of php.

For example, I could not figure out why my migrations would not run - artisan commands failed for no apparent reason, when a nearly identical local setup worked.  Come to find out that my root folder was set to 5.2 something.  A quick chat session with the webhost guys, and they showed me how to fix.  Presto- migrations work.

Much of the rest of my application worked, but the artisan functionality is a no-can-do-without for me.  Hope that helps.

Also, the [built-in php development web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) is handy - starts with 5.4.

EDIT: Here is a little more ammo for you: another specific issue I encountered:

```
root@Grisbuntu:/home/ryan/MyApp6# php /usr/bin/composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- zizaco/entrust dev-master requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.

...

root@Grisbuntu:/home/ryan/MyApp6# php -v
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Mar 11 2013 14:31:48)
```

So there you have it: Entrust is one specific example of a package you cannot use without 5.4....

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
php -v

...PHP 5.4.15-1~precise+1 (cli) (built: May 13 2013 16:00:00)

composer update
...
```

I hope that helps someone!

UPDATE: July 2013, per [php.net](http://www.php.net/) : Please Note: This will be the last regular release of the PHP 5.3 series. All users of PHP are encouraged to upgrade to PHP 5.4 or PHP 5.5. **The PHP 5.3 series will receive only security fixes for the next year.**

Comment: Thank you for your feedback ! Artisan and built-in php server out, ok. What about encryption, database access or email ? Did you experiment some issues in this domains ?

Comment: Sorry, i did not test those.  Why can't the server's php version just be upgraded?  Not doing so is short term thinking, imo.  Laravel is awesome, and not upgrading a free program (php) seems like an ignorant move.  Are there legitimate backwards-compatibility concerns between php 5.3.3 and 5.3.7?  You'll regret the day you need artisan, which is, uh every day.  It's part of what makes laravel awesome.  5.3.7 is a requirement, not a suggestion.Seriously, why not?

Comment: I'm in the commercial part of my job, I work on a public-sector market so I can't really dialog with my client now. I just know that an upgrade like this one have to go through a stupid bureaucratic process... But, of course, my recommandation will be to upgrade. I just need few concrete arguments.

Comment: "All PHP users should note that the PHP 5.2 series is NOT supported anymore. All users are strongly encouraged to upgrade to PHP 5.3.7."  BTW: the current version is [5.5.0](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.0).  Can anyone explain the possible objection to this from the company's perspective?  How could this be subject to any beaurocratic process?  Why don't all webhosts automatically update php?  Can that cause problems?  If so, what problems?

Comment: @Ryan Some companies have policies which prevent upgrades. For example, one company I know use RHEL6 on their server. Redhat's official support is for PHP 5.3.3. Security fixes are back ported by Redhat but not features. The only way to get a newer version is to install from a non official repository or build from source. Either of these could be against company policy.

Comment: http://www.php.net/ : Please Note: This will be the last regular release of the PHP 5.3 series. All users of PHP are encouraged to upgrade to PHP 5.4 or PHP 5.5. [b]The PHP 5.3 series will receive only security fixes for the next year.[/b]